# Powershell form padding of picture in button

Tags: powershell

Im trying to create Form in Powershell. But I cant figure out how Can I remove padding from button when I have image in it? As you can see on the picture. There is space between picture and border of button. How Can I remove it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK9ig.jpg

```
$Item1But = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$Item1But.Text = "Keyboard"
$Item1But.Width = 250
$Item1But.Height = 50
$Item1But.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile(".\Picture\Keyboard.gif")
$Item1But.TextImageRelation = "ImageBeforeText"
$Item1But.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$Item1But.FlatAppearance.BorderSize=2
$Item1But.FlatAppearance.Bordercolor="red"
$Item1But.location = new-object system.drawing.point(25,25)
$Item1But.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,25"
$Item1But.add_click($NewAction)
$Form.controls.Add($Item1But)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [MSDN on Padding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
$Item1But.Padding = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (0,0,0,0)
```